# Access default function argument values by name/identifier

Tags: python, function, default-value

Consider the following simplified example:

```
def f(string, offset=0):
    print(string[offset:] if isinstance(offset, int) else string[f.__defaults__[0]:])

f('Hello', 'two')
```

While the tuple returned by `f.__defaults__` gives access to all default argument values in the respective order (i. e. **by position**), I wonder if there is a way to access them **by name/identifier** of the argument (here: `'offset'`) from within the function ...

Comment: If you are controlling the code here, you can just use the value you set as default: `... else string[0:]`

Comment: @schwobaseggl I think the idea here is to apply the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle. Imagine having to search for and modify 10 places in the code where the default value of `offset` is used when later the default value has to change if you hardcoded `0` in each of those places.

Comment: @blhsing That makes sense. On a different note: This will be called by other code. Passing a badly typed parameter is not an error I would silence, but rather want to know about so I can fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `inspect.signature` to obtain the parameters of a given function, from which mapping you can get the default value of a named parameter:

```
import inspect

def f(string, offset=0):
    print(string[offset:] if isinstance(offset, int) else string[f_params['offset'].default:])

f_params = inspect.signature(f).parameters
```